# JS Fetch headers probelm

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get basic json data. I tried on the Postman, it works but I can't do this on my code. Fetch not send my headers. Riot API needs the X-Riot-Token header.

By the way I got cors error and I fixed this with no-cors mode.

```js
fetch('https://tr1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/boby', {
          method: 'GET',
          mode: 'no-cors',
          headers: {
            "X-Riot-Token": "RGAPI-SOME-NUMBERS-XXXXXXXXX"
          }
        })
          .then(res => console.log(res))
```

I got 401 unauthorized error on Google Chrome console.

Comment: What does postman returns.

Comment: Are you sure headers not sent? Did you inspect the actual request in dev tools network? Might be they don't want ajax requests to prevent you exposing your credentials and expect you to use a proxy

Comment: @SandeepRanjan postman returns normal response which I want